# MODX REVO + php mysql - insert data to specified table row

Tags: php, mysql, modx-revolution

I'm trying to add some data to a custom-db-table like this:

```
$sql ="insert into ext_user_data (userdata_id,vorname,nachname) values('$id','$vorname','$nachname')";
$stmt = $modx->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

This works fine, expect by using this code I'm getting a new row in the table ext_user_data. I want to add this data to an existing row like this:

```
$sql ="insert into ext_user_data where id='136'(userdata_id,vorname,nachname) values('$id','$vorname','$nachname')";
$stmt = $modx->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

But by using this code nothing gets added to the db-table.

So how can I add something to this custom-db-table to a given primary key? The primary key is the same as the $id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update data to an existing row you use a different SQL command, your code should look like this:

```
$sql ="update ext_user_data set `vorname` = '$vorname', `nachname` = '$nachname' where id='$id'";
$stmt = $modx->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: thank you Yoel, this works fine...can you please tell me what to do if the table-row doesn't exist yet and needs to be created? I just discovered that this case might happen that the table-row doesn't exist.

Comment: @EMEm you are welcome. To do that you will have to write a query like "SELECT `id` FROM ext_user_data WHERE `id` = '$id'" and then check how many rows using $stmt->num_rows or something similar. you can check out more info [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: oh, didn't see your new comment...now I'm using this: if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT ext_user_data WHERE userid = '$id'"))){
// Code inside if block if userid is already there
$sql ="update ext_user_data set `vorname` = '$vorname', `nachname` = '$nachname' where id='$id'";
$stmt = $modx->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
} 
else {
$sql ="insert into ext_user_data (id,userdata_id,vorname,nachname) values('$id','$id','$vorname','$nachname')";
$stmt = $modx->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
}
...seems to be working...